# Can you recover from a "Resource 1 not found"? in Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, resources, corruption

A fairly complex project was muddling along with lots of work done last night when I decided to turn in. But thinking about adding some gestures got me up after three hours of sleep and I went at the code again, which was a mistake. I added the gesture manager and then sleepily hit the F1 key to look up the help on gestures. Coming back from THAT mistake, Delphi 2010 froze. I had compiled just before adding the gesture manager, so I presumed no big thing. I was wrong. When I used task manager to close down D2010, things didn't come back right. Lots of complaints about Nexus databases. Then, on compiling I through a fit about the res file. In and out of the IDE, renaming the res file and letting it be recreated. But on run, the program complains about "Resource 1 not found" and then proceeds to run, ignoring the INI file settings to place the form on the screen. Furthermore, it has the interesting side effect of making controls (NextSuite's FlipPanels) DISAPPEAR when clicked, instead of expanding the panel. All quite ... mind-blowing. My backup is about 21 hours old and I'd rather not lose the work done in the interim. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When I deleted and recreated the .RES file, Delphi didn't automatically default to turning on version information. A routine from one of the procedures in a closed routine was trying to read that resource and producing the 'very' informative error.

Lessons learned from this fiasco:

1. Turning on version resource in the IDE does NOT survive the recreation of the resource file
2. You have to have source code to all of your third party libraries.

Ahhh well, live and learn. Time and time again.